# Cloud-9: How to open a file in the c9-editor from c9-terminal

Tags: cloud9-ide

Is there a way to open a file not from the workspace tree view but from the c9-terminal tab?

Background: c9 doesn´t allow me to set the workspace path to / for a user who doesn´t have write access there. But I´d like have a look around and change files outside of the main project directory (virtual hosts, php ini, etc). Using the terminal I can roam around everywhere my user has read access.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

At the moment, the only way to open a file from the terminal is in vim or by using `ls` and then clicking on the file you'd like to open.

**Edit**: You can now open from the terminal by running `npm install -g c9`, then doing `c9 file.ext` or `c9 open file.ext`

Comment: Tried it, doesn´t work for files outside of the file tree (workspace path). Error: "No files found that match [FILENAME]"

Comment: Oh I see, I also am unable to open anything below my ubuntu folder. It looks like this is a limitation at the moment and you'll need to use vim to open anything below the ubuntu folder.

Comment: Just tried this and it worked great (without restarting the workspace even)!

Comment: Old thread, but I was looking for this solution, too. Now this works without restarting the workspace.

Comment: Hey, I have this working. However, when collaborating it opens the files for everyone logged into the environment. Is there a way to open files just for me?

Answer (score 14):

Borrowing from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/793988/open-file-from-cloud9s-terminal-bash-in-its-ide),

```
c9 open <filename>
```

Comment: I get a "bash: c9: command not found". Where do I find the c9 command line client?

Comment: See Brady's answer... you may need to install `c9` first with something like `sudo npm install -g c9`.

Answer (score 9):

You can do the next:

```
cd ~
ln -s / root
```

Then you can see the root link in the workspace. You can navigate 
through it and open any file (If you do not see the ~ folder in your favorites section, mark the 'Show Home in Favorites' option)

[image: Root folder in ~]

If you prefer, (once you've installed c9) you can open files from the terminal with:

```
c9 open ~/root/...
```

NOTE: You can open files but not save them if they require superuser permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Preferences -> Settings -> Terminal, there is an option "Use Cloud9 as the Default Editor". If you enable this option and open a terminal, the `EDITOR` env variable will look like this:

```
$ echo $EDITOR
`which c9` open --wait
```

The path to c9 in my case is:

```
/mnt/shared/sbin/c9
```

For some reason, this didn't work for me initially, but now it works flawlessly. Perhaps the above default editor setting has to be enabled for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I've just written into `/mnt/shared/plugins/google.cloud/etc/gitconfig`. First I was not allowed to write it, in nano. But using "c9 open" - just closing the tab with `.gitconfig` saved my changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open any file from / the cloud 9 IDE must have permission.
While configuring the C9 IDE give root as the user name and copy paste the public key in .ssh folder of root, allow root login in the ssh d config ,then you will be able to edit any file from the IDE.

Comment: or install c9 as sudo