# .gitignore file won't show in Cloud9 file panel

Tags: git, ubuntu, command-line, cloud9-ide

I am working on a ruby on rails application. I use the Cloud9 online IDE, which is Ubuntu.

When I go to the root directory, I can't open my .gitignore file. I know I'm in the right spot because when I'm in root and I type `ls -la` it lists all of my files, including `.gitignore`

I've seen other threads and some suggest using either *open* or *see*, followed by *.gitignore*. And they always work for OP.
But neither of them work for me.

I tried this one:

```
open .gitignore`
```

But when I use that, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

And when I use this command:

```
see .gitignore
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: unknown mime-type for ".gitignore" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"
```

If anyone has any idea what's going on, please help me out. I can't find any other fix from other threads, other than using the two commands above.

Comment: The `open` command likely isn't specific to Cloud9 (the error appears to match [`open(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/open)) and you probably need to use a different command with the editor. [Another Q&A here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028178/cloud-9-how-to-open-a-file-in-the-c9-editor-from-c9-terminal) suggests `c9 open .gitignore`, possibly needing to install it. (Haven't tried it myself, though.)

Comment: Using `c9 open .gitignore` worked. Thank you. Wish I could make this the confirmed answer, but Callum arrived first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you see it in the left hand side bar? If not, in the left hand side bar click the little cog icon and then click 'show hidden files'.
[image: Show Hidden Files]

Hope this helped.

Comment: It worked! Wow, I feel like a dunce. Thank you very much, Callum. I'm still confused as to why I couldn't open it with the terminal command, but for the purposes I need it at the moment, this is a perfectly adequate fix. Thank you very much.